# Permissions.getAsync or Permissions.askAsync Not working in RealseAPK on Expo SDK33

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

#### Steps to Reproduce

Connect the actual device to the Android studio, start an extension, and then click the Run app button in the Android studio to install the app on the device. The permissions check is successful in this app.

However, after 'expo publish' build  => signed Bundle APK => select APK => click release=>   V1,V2 Check => APK on the device to run.

Pressing a button does not generate an alert for the privilege.

#### Expected Behavior

Shall be operated like a  simulator apk.

#### Actual Behavior

The actual APK does not notify you of any permissions.

#### Reproducible Demo

https://snack.expo.io/H1sswTuyS

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Modal,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Alert,
  NativeModules
} from "react-native";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      alertVisibility: true
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingLeft: 25 }} onPress={() => {}}>
          <Ionicons
            name={"ios-arrow-back"}
            size={30}
            color={"#ffffff"}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),

      headerRight: null
    };
  };



  showCustomAlert(visible) {
    this.setState({ alertVisibility: visible });
  }

  okButton = async () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonColor: "#ffd90d"
    });
    const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (permission.status !== "granted") {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

      if (newPermission.status === "granted") {
        const permission2 = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        if (permission2.status !== "granted") {
          const newPermission2 = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
          if (newPermission2.status === "granted") {
            const permission3 = await Permissions.getAsync(
              Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
            );
            if (permission3.status !== "granted") {
              const newPermission3 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
              );
              if (newPermission3.status === "granted") {
                const permission4 = await Permissions.getAsync(
                  Permissions.REMINDERS
                );
                if (permission4.status !== "granted") {
                  const newPermission4 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                    Permissions.REMINDERS
                  );
                  if (newPermission4.status === "granted") {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  } else {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  }
                }
                if (permission4.status === "granted") {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                } else {
                 console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                }
              } else {
                const permission4 = await Permissions.getAsync(
                  Permissions.REMINDERS
                );
                if (permission4.status !== "granted") {
                  const newPermission4 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                    Permissions.REMINDERS
                  );
                  if (newPermission4.status === "granted") {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  } else {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  }
                }
                if (permission4.status === "granted") {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                } else {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                }
              }
            }
            if (permission3.status === "granted") {
              console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
            } else {
               console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
            }
          } else {
            const permission3 = await Permissions.getAsync(
              Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
            );
            if (permission3.status !== "granted") {
              const newPermission3 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
              );
              if (newPermission3.status === "granted") {
                const permission4 = await Permissions.getAsync(
                  Permissions.REMINDERS
                );
                if (permission4.status !== "granted") {
                  const newPermission4 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                    Permissions.REMINDERS
                  );
                  if (newPermission4.status === "granted") {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  } else {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  }
                }
                if (permission4.status === "granted") {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                } else {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                }
              } else {
                console.log(
                    "permission3.status not granted"
                  );
                const permission4 = await Permissions.getAsync(
                  Permissions.REMINDERS
                );
                if (permission4.status !== "granted") {
                  const newPermission4 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                    Permissions.REMINDERS
                  );
                  if (newPermission4.status === "granted") {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  } else {
                    this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
                  }
                }
                if (permission4.status === "granted") {
                  console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
                } else {
                  console.log("permission4.status not granted");
                }
              }
            }
            if (permission3.status === "granted") {
              console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
            }
          }
        }
        if (permission2.status === "granted") {
          console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
        } else {
          console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
        }
      } else {
        alert("close");
      }
    } else {
      if (permission.status === "granted") {
        console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
      } else {
        console.log(
                    "permission4.status not granted"
                  );
      }
    }
  };

  androidButton = async () => {
    const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (permission.status !== "granted") {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (newPermission.status === "granted") {
        const permission2 = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        if (permission2.status !== "granted") {
          const newPermission2 = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
          if (newPermission2.status === "granted") {
            const permission3 = await Permissions.getAsync(
              Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
            );
            if (permission3.status !== "granted") {
              const newPermission3 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
              );
              if (newPermission3.status === "granted") {
                this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
              }
            }
            if (permission3.status === "granted") {
              this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
              this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
            } else {
              console.log("permission3.status not granted");
            }
          } else {
            const permission3 = await Permissions.getAsync(
              Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
            );
            if (permission3.status !== "granted") {
              const newPermission3 = await Permissions.askAsync(
                Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
              );
              if (newPermission3.status === "granted") {
                this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
              } else {
                this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
              }
            }
            if (permission3.status === "granted") {
              this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
              this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
            }
          }
        }
        if (permission2.status === "granted") {
          this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
          this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "info",
          `Text`,
          [
            {
              text: "ok",
              onPress: () => alert("close")
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      }
    } else {
      const permission2 = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      if (permission2.status !== "granted") {
        const newPermission2 = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        if (newPermission2.status === "granted") {
          this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
          this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
        } else {
          this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
          this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
        }
      } else {
        this.setState({ alertVisibility: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterWalletIndex");
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.alertVisibility}
          transparent={true}
          animationType={"fade"}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.showCustomAlert(!this.state.alertVisibility);
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              height: "100%",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.8)"
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.alertmainview}>
              <Text style={styles.alerttitle}>Text</Text>

              <View
                style={{
                  width: "60%",
                  height: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "#fed80c",
                  marginLeft: 20
                }}
              />

              <Text style={styles.alertmessage}>
               Text
              </Text>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Text</Text>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    backgroundColor: "#efefef",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    marginRight: 20,
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    marginBottom: 10
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.subtitletextstorage}>Text</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.subtitletext2}>Text</Text>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Text Text</Text>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    backgroundColor: "#efefef",
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    marginRight: 20,
                    borderRadius: 3
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 6 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitletext}>Text</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitletext2}>Text Text</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      paddingTop: 8,
                      paddingBottom: 8
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.subtitletext}>Text</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitletext2}>
                      Text
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  width: "90%",
                  height: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "#fed80c",
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  marginTop: 20
                }}
              />

              <View
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  alignItems: "flex-end",
                  paddingRight: 20,
                  paddingTop: 10
                }}
              >
                <TouchableHighlight
                  underlayColor="#ffd90d"
                  style={styles.buttonStyle}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Platform.OS === "ios"
                      ? this.okButton()
                      : this.androidButton()
                  }
                >
                  <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> ok </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 180, height: 180 }}
          source={require("./assets/snack-icon.png")}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: Platform.OS == "ios" ? 20 : 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.8)"
  },

  alertmainview: {
    width: "90%",
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },

  alerttitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "left",
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 10
  },

  alertmessage: {
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 20
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginLeft: 20,
    paddingTop: 12,
    fontSize: 12,
    paddingBottom: 8
  },
  subtitletext: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 14
  },
  subtitletextstorage: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 6,
    marginBottom: 6
  },
  subtitletext2: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#434343"
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    width: 60,
    height: 34,
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginBottom: 18
  },

  TextStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

export default App;
```

#### Environment

Expo CLI 2.20.2 environment info:
    System:

- OS: macOS 10.14.5
- Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash

  Binaries:
- Node: 10.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.15.2 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm
- Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman

  IDEs:
- Android Studio: 3.3 AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842
- Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

  npmGlobalPackages:
- expo-cli: 2.20.2
- "react-native":
  "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
- "expo": "^33.0.0",
- "expo-ads-admob": "~5.0.1",
- Android real device : LGM-V300S.
- Android Studio 3.3.2
- macOS 10.14.5
- Standalone App(ExpoKit)